# Calling API from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, api

I'm new to SQL Server. I would like to pull data from an AppsFlyer website, which requires some information like date in the format yyyy-MM-dd and an API key.

Here's a example of the API I need to use:

```
https://hq.appsflyer.com/export/br.com.mottu/partners_report/v5?api_token={Account owner API key should be used}&from=yyyy-mm-dd&to=yyyy-mm-dd
```

Here's the website
https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207034346-Pull-APIs-Pulling-AppsFlyer-Reports-by-APIs

Comment: SQL Server is your **database server** - it's not the place to be calling out to external URL and services from there¨

Comment: You will be wanting to create a script or program that will call the API, process the returned response, and then update the data store (your database).

Comment: Your other option is creating a CLR component that will allow you to make an external call and return its result to SQL for processing. It's a fairly involved process, so depending on your need it may or may not be worth the effort.